# Does MSSQL 2000 run in VMWare ESX?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esx, sql-server

Does MSSQL 2000 run in VMware ESX? We are planning on going into a virtualized environment and are wondering if main production database will run in VMware ESX. We cannot upgrade the SQL version.

Comment: VMware *what*? VMware is a company which make several virtualization products. If you really want a VMware related tag on this question, please edit back in a product specific one as I have removed the [vmware] tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it runs just fine in VMware - hopefully it's a lightly loaded database server rather than a multi-terabyte monster!

Ideally, you'd want a fresh install of Windows and SQL Server 2000, but failing that a P2V will work. Brent Ozar refers to it as taking care of dinosaurs:

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/08/sql-p2v-what-really-killed-the-dinosaurs/

and

http://www.brentozar.com/community/virtualization-best-practices/

The only time I got caught out with this approach was when a SQL2000/Windows2000 box was cloned (P2V), and then taken from its original domain to a new domain. SQL got a bit confused as the servername is embedded during install.

Comment: Cool, our guys helping with the conversion we concerned about it. This restores my confidence, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with dozens of legacy systems.  Without fail, they run better in the virtualized environment (which is newer hardware).  The flexibility to move between physical systems, free up (or preferably, retire) hardware, and consolidate is just great.

The dogma around SQL Server not playing well with virtualization amazingly still lingers, and is still misguided.  Unless you're running on a [type 2 hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) or have overcommitted resources, it's straightforward to make SQL Server play well with others.